# Regex: How do I get this negative lookahead to work?

Tags: regex, grep, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to do some visitor stats info on raw Apache logs. I want to match all lines where the referral URL is NOT by host URL. The specifics about Apache, etc. are not the important part. Here are two example lines from my log:

```
1.2.3.4 - - [07/Jun/2023:11:15:08 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "https://www.google.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
1.2.3.4 - - [07/Jun/2023:11:15:08 -0500] "GET /page.html HTTP/1.1" 200 505921 "https://www.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

I want to match on the first string containing the referral from Google (or any other URL or empty string) but NOT match the second string from the host URL of example.com.

Here is the regex I thought would work but does not. I've been using regex101.com to test:

```
/1.2.3.4(.*)GET (\/ HTTP|\/(.*)htm)(.*)(200|304)(.*)(?!example)/g
```

If I remove the (?!example) part it matches all the pageview lines so I feel like I'm close. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to use `(?!.*example)`. `.*` has to be inside the lookahead. Otherwise it will just make the precding `.*` match something that isn't followed by `example`

Comment: Then use another `.*` after the lookahead to get the rest of the line.

Comment: These both work in regex101.com but not with grep. Why would that be?

Comment: What version of grep? What options are you using? Only GNU grep works with Perl style regex and you need `-P` to use them.

Comment: This should do the job in Perl, I have tested it and it works (^(?!.*\bexample\b).*$)